# Float number with OpenCL in CPU, doesn't appear the decimal part

Tags: opencl, cpu, jocl

I have this code in OpenCL:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global float *C) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    float t =3.5f;
    C[i] = t;
}
```

When I run in GPU the return in variable C is 3.5, so it's ok.
But when I run in CPU the return is 3.0.
This happen with any float value.

But if I run this code:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const float A, __global float *C) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A;
}
```

And I passed the 3.5 value to variable A, this run ok in CPU and GPU.

Why this happen?

Comment: What is your CPU-side (host side) code?

Comment: I'm trying to execute this code with OpenCL in CPU, I think that CPU is host and device side. Am I right?

Comment: What calls are you using to set the kernel parameters, how are you reading the value back etc etc. We need all of that code in order to help you.